# Time.new does not work as I would expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to generate some seed material.

```
seed_array.each do |seed|
    Task.create(date: Date.new(2012,06,seed[1]), start_t: Time.new(2012,6,2,seed[2],seed[3]), end_t: Time.new(2012,6,2,seed[2] + 2,seed[3]), title: "#{seed[0]}")
end
```

Ultimately I will put random hours, minutes, seconds. The problem that I am facing is that instead of creating a time with the 2012-06-02 date it creates a time with a different date: 2000-01-01.

I tested `Time.new(2012,6,2,2,20,45)` in rails console and it works as expected. When I am trying to seed my database however some voodoo magic happens and I don't get the date I want.

Any inputs are appreciated. Thank you!

**Update1:**

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction   SQL
(0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "date", "description",
  "end_t", "group_id", "start_t", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?,
  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:15:34 UTC
  +00:00], ["date", Thu, 07 Jun 2012], ["description", nil],
  ["end_t", 2012-06-02 10:02:00 -0400], ["group_id", nil],
  ["start_t", 2012-06-02 08:02:00 -0400], ["title", "99"],
  ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:15:34 UTC +00:00]]
(2.3ms)  commit transaction
```

This is a small sample of the log.

**Update 2**

```
Task id: 101, date: "2012-06-26", start_t: "2000-01-01 08:45:00", end_t: "2000-01-01 10:45:00", title: "1", description: nil, group_id: nil, created_at: "2012-07-03 02:15:33", updated_at: "2012-07-03 02:15:33"
```

This is what shows up in rails console.

Comment: What is the generated SQL from the log?

Comment: @MarkThomas I included the log. It seems like my problem was in displaying the time. Thank you Mark! You pointed a newbie in the right direction.

Comment: @MarkThomas Woops I spoke to soon. The problem wasn't in displaying the time. When I go to rails console and I hit Task.all I can see that the data was not saved properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you used the `:time` type for your `start_t` and `end_t`. In that context time refers to a pure time of day data type, with no date, because that's what the SQL time type is.

Ruby's `Time` type covers both date and time, so your database column needs to be :datetime. In fact ruby has no pure time of day class so activerecord uses a regular Time with a bogus date instead.

Comment: I changed it to :datetime and it works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested you code like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3]

arr.each do |seed|
    Timetest.create(time: Time.new(2012,6,2,2,20,45), title: "#{seed}")
end
```

And its working as expected. But i got this sql on my console and its a bit different than yours in your start_t and end_t

```
 SQL (4.1ms)  INSERT INTO "timetests" ("created_at", "time", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:11:35 UTC +00:00], ["time", Sat, 02 Jun 2012 07:20:45 UTC +00:00], ["title", "1"], ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:11:35 UTC +00:00]]
```

**Update 1**

Have you tried to use DateTime.new instead of Time.new?

```
Task.create(date: DateTime.new(2012,06,seed[1]), start_t: DateTime.new(2012,6,2,seed[2],seed[3]), end_t: DateTime.new(2012,6,2,seed[2] + 2,seed[3]), title: "#{seed[0]}")
```

Comment: You can find it under Update 2. It doesn't look ok. It saves it as 2000

Comment: What version do you have of RoR? I notice that in you sql you are inserting other formats for the date time. 
"start_t" , 2012-06-02 08:02:00 -0400 
"updated_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:15:34 UTC +00:00

When i try it out with ruby 1.9.3 my sql looks like this:
 SQL (4.1ms)  INSERT INTO "timetests" ("created_at", "time", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:11:35 UTC +00:00], ["time", Sat, 02 Jun 2012 07:20:45 UTC +00:00], ["title", "1"], ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 02:11:35 UTC +00:00]]

Comment: I am using rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Date.new does not store time... I need that.

Comment: Sorry my bad, DateTime.new() it will give you the date and time. [Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)

Comment: DateTime.new returns the same thing

Comment: I am sure it is something simple. I think I am just to tired to see it tonight. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: DateTime.new(2012,06)
 => Fri, 01 Jun 2012 00:00:00 +0000  At least i got this on my console, but if you figure it out just let me know see ya pal